# Read files sent with spark-submit by the driver

Tags: apache-spark

I am sending a Spark job to run on a remote cluster by running

```
spark-submit ... --deploy-mode cluster --files some.properties ...
```

I want to read the content of the `some.properties` file by the **driver** code, i.e. before creating the Spark context and launching RDD tasks. The file is copied to the remote driver, but not to the driver's working directory.

The ways around this problem that I know of are:

1. Upload the file to HDFS
2. Store the file in the app jar

Both are inconvenient since this file is frequently changed on the submitting dev machine.

Is there a way to read the file that was uploaded using the `--files` flag during the driver code main method?

Comment: You could put the file on a network mount that is accessible by all the nodes on the cluster. This way you can just read from that mount in your driver program. You could expose a simple endpoint that returns the file. This way your driver program can make an http call.

Comment: True enough, @AlexNaspo, but redundant. The file is transferred alongside with the driver jar, and is stored on the same file system on the server, just not in the same folder. Sending it *again* over HTTP seems wasteful.

Comment: If you go with @AlexNaspo's suggestion then you won't need to pass the properties file in via `--files`  so it wouldn't be redundant?

Answer (score 34):

Yes, you can access files uploaded via the `--files` argument.

This is how I'm able to access files passed in via `--files`:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--class com.MyClass \
--master yarn-cluster \
--files /path/to/some/file.ext \
--jars lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
/path/to/app.jar file.ext
```

and in my Spark code:

```
val filename = args(0)
val linecount = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.size
```

I do believe these files are downloaded onto the workers in the same directory as the jar is placed, which is why simply passing the filename and not the absolute path to `Source.fromFile` works.

Comment: This is what I tried. The file is copied to the workers' work directory, but not to the driver's directory. Maybe it is different in YARN mode.

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked that you weren't running in YARN mode. There's a helper class called [`SparkFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$). `SparkFiles.get(filename)` will return the path where `filename` was downloaded to, but you won't be able to use it until after the Spark context is initialized. Is there any particular reason you need to read the file before the Spark context is initialized?

Comment: I use some of these properties to set Spark parameters

Comment: The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) say `"every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server"`. Does that mean a simple `/path/to/some/file` that is stored locally on the `master` (or whatever you call the system from where one is executing `spark-submit`) would be sufficient? Or do I need to either provide an `hdfs://` path or manually put the file at specified path in each `executor` beforehand?

Comment: To pass more than one file, is it a `,` or a space between file names?

Comment: @ChrisMarotta yes, you can pass multiple files using `,` and `--files`

Comment: What if the path was in an object store like S3 instead of a filesystem? Or is this not compatible with `--files`?

Answer (score 7):

The `--files` and `--archives` options support specifying file names with the `#` , just like Hadoop.

For example you can specify: `--files localtest.txt#appSees.txt` and this will upload the file you have locally named `localtest.txt` into Spark worker directory, but this will be linked to by the name `appSees.txt`, and your application should use the name as `appSees.txt` to reference it when running on YARN.

this works for my spark streaming application in both yarn/client and yarn/cluster mode.

Comment: Hey - this isn't working for me. Could you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293447/how-to-rename-a-file-when-providing-to-spark-via-files) and see if you can tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

After the investigation, I found one solution for above issue.  Send the **any.properties** configuration during spark-submit and use it by spark driver before and after SparkSession initialization. Hope it will help you.

**any.properties**

```
spark.key=value
spark.app.name=MyApp
```

**SparkTest.java**

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class SparkTest{

  public Static void main(String[] args){

    String warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();

    Config conf = loadConf();
    System.out.println(conf.getString("spark.key"));

    // Initialize SparkContext and use configuration from properties
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(conf.getString("spark.app.name"));

    SparkSession sparkSession = 
    SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

  }


  public static Config loadConf() {

      String configFileName = "any.properties";
      System.out.println(configFileName);
      Config configs = ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File(configFileName)));
      System.out.println(configs.getString("spark.key")); // get value from properties file
      return configs;
   }
}
```

**Spark Submit:**

```
spark-submit --class SparkTest --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files any.properties,yy-site.xml --jars ...........
```

Answer (score 6):

use `spark-submit --help`, will find that this option is only for working directory of executor not driver.

`--files FILES: Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor.`

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, I find it really interesting to achieve this easily, first arrange your working directory like this:

```
/path/to/your/workdir/
|--code.py
|--file.txt
```

and then in your code.py main function, just read the file as usual:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = open("./file.txt").read()
```

then submit it without any specific configurations as follows:

```
spark-submit code.py
```

it runs correctly which amazes me. I suppose the submit process archives any files and sub-dir files altogether and sends them to the driver in pyspark, while you should archive them yourself in scala version. By the way, both --files and --archives options are working in worker not the driver, which means you can only access these files in RDD transformations or actions.

Comment: `open("./file.txt")` is **not** Spark code. All you're doing here is running Python directly on the driver node. Last I checked, the "current working directory" is not bundled with `spark-submit`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice solution I developed in Python Spark in order to integrate any data as a file from outside to your Big Data platform.

Have fun.

```
# Load from the Spark driver any local text file and return a RDD (really useful in YARN mode to integrate new data at the fly)
# (See https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/38482/loading-local-file-to-apache-spark.html)
def parallelizeTextFileToRDD(sparkContext, localTextFilePath, splitChar):
    localTextFilePath = localTextFilePath.strip(' ')
    if (localTextFilePath.startswith("file://")):
        localTextFilePath = localTextFilePath[7:]
    import subprocess
    dataBytes = subprocess.check_output("cat " + localTextFilePath, shell=True)
    textRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(dataBytes.split(splitChar))
    return textRDD

# Usage example
myRDD = parallelizeTextFileToRDD(sc, '~/myTextFile.txt', '\n') # Load my local file as a RDD
myRDD.saveAsTextFile('/user/foo/myTextFile') # Store my data to HDFS
```

Comment: Why `cat` a file when you can `open()` it from Python? Also, this seems counterintuitive to the actual `--files`/`--archives` support

Answer (score 0):

A way around the problem is that you can create a temporary `SparkContext` simply by calling `SparkContext.getOrCreate()` and then read the file you passed in the `--files` with the help of `SparkFiles.get('FILE')`.

Once you read the file retrieve all necessary configuration you required in a `SparkConf()` variable.

After that call this function:

```
SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
```

This will distroy the existing `SparkContext` and than in the next line simply initalize a new `SparkContext` with the necessary configurations like this.

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

You got yourself a `SparkContext` with the desired settings