# Spark Cassandra connector write Dataframe to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a dataframe which I want to write to Cassandra table. The data frame consists of 4,680,820 rows. The data itself is coming from .csv file which is around 650MB large and read by spark Cassandra connector from datastax.

Then, using Spark Cassandra connector to write this data in dataframe to cassandra. The connector does write records but not all. It is currently only writing 17349 records. How should I optimize the writes and also write all the 4.6 million records. I have 8 Exeuctors and each executor has 4 cores each so today of 28 tasks can be run in parallel.

I am using Cassandra 3.0.13 and Spark 2.1.0 and Spark Cassandra Connector:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.1

This is the code I am using:

```
 def writeToCassandra(df: DataFrame, tableName: String) {
    if (df.take(1).length>0){
        println("Number of rows in DF are: "+ df.count);
        df.write
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .mode("overwrite")
        .options(Map(
            "header" -> "true",
            "output.batch.grouping.key" -> "none",
            "cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec" -> "1MB",
            "table" -> tableName, 
            "keyspace" -> "vardb_irc", 
            "cluster" -> "CassandraPOCluster")
            )
        .save()
    }
    else{
        println("Dataframe is empty");
    }
}
```

The above method is called by below method.

```
def runCSVDataSourceImport(){
    // Load the CM data into with SPARkSQL
    val adErDF = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("file:///opt/risk-4.20170511.csv")

   println("DF: adErDF ready to use")
   println(adErDF.count);
   val adErDFRepartition = adErDF.repartition(3)
   adErDFRepartition.explain
   writeToCassandra(adErDFRepartition, "risk_4");
}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you share your code? And where is the file located?

Comment: Added the code above

Comment: Hello @morfious902002 can you elaborate on your last comment please? also I do not want truncate and add the data in that table will append work in that case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900023/read-files-sent-with-spark-submit-by-the-driver  Try this answer by Ton. And append will only add data to that table without deleting or overriding existing data.

Comment: the csv is getting read fine in the data frame and dataframe has the exact same record count as the file. The problem is during the write operation it doesn't write all the records.

Comment: try .mode("overwrite") to .mode("append") If this gives you correct result then we can look into other solution for not dropping the table.

Comment: check the data model, it might be upserting instead of inserting. maybe add another column as a clustering key that can provide uniqueness to the data.

Comment: doesn't work. the number of records remain same 17349

Comment: Just a guess but can you change "cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec" -> "48MB" and test.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I thinking I was ovewriting the data in the Cassandra because of the primary key was getting dumplicated during data ingestion and thus overwriting the records written earlier..

Comment: It seems, primary keys are duplicate. Data is being overwritten as token is hashed on partition keys. Please choose a set of keys as primary and clustering key in you cassandra table, if you don't have a single column which has all values unique.