# Spark submit job fails for cluster mode but works in local for copyToLocal from HDFS in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, spark-submit

I'm running a Java code to copy the files from HDFS to local using Spark cluster mode in spark submit.
The job runs fine with spark local but fails in cluster mode.
It throws a java.io.exeception: Target /mypath/ is a directory.

I don't understand why is it failing in cluster. But I don't recieve any exceptions in local.

Comment: Since you are running job in cluster mode, there are few processes that runs in  a parallel. Each of them has own log and you need to check there for exact stacktrace.

Comment: try with entering fully qualified hdfs path.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is because in the first case (local) your driver is in the same machine that you are running the whole Spark job. In the second case (cluster), your driver program is shipped to one of your workers and execute the process from there.

In general, when you want to run Spark jobs as a cluster mode and you need to pre-process local files such as JSON, XML, among others, you need to ship them along with the executable using the following sentence `--files <myfile>`. Then in your driver program you will be able to see that particular file. If you want to include multiple files, put them separated by comma`(,)`.

The approach is the same when you want to add some jars dependencies, you need to use `--jars <myJars>`.

For more details about this, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900023/read-files-sent-with-spark-submit-by-the-driver).

Comment: But I'm talking about the HDFS File target exception. It shouldn't throw a exception there. As worker nodes can access HDFS too

Comment: @EmmaVaze try with entering fully qualified hdfs path.