# How to rename a file when providing to Spark via --files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Referencing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848764/1040915) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10858), I expect that I should be able to change the name by which a file is referenced in Spark by using an octothorpe - that is, if I call `spark-submit --files local-file-name.json#spark-file-name.json`, I should then be able to reference the file as `spark-file-name.json`. However, this doesn't appear to be the case:

```
$ cat ../differentDirectory/local-file-name.json
{
  "name": "Adam",
  "age": 25
}

$ cat testing1.py
import os
import json
import time
from pyspark import SparkFiles, SparkContext

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir('.'))
sc = SparkContext('local', 'App For Testing --files upload')
print(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory())
print(os.listdir(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()))
print(json.load(open(SparkFiles.get('local-file-name.json'))))

$ spark-submit --files ../differentDirectory/local-file-name.json testing1.py
20/08/06 17:05:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
/private/tmp/sparkSubmitTesting
['testing.py']
...
/private/var/folders/0q/qw3xxl5x2yx1rf1nncl6s4rw2yzhgq/T/spark-2d052f27-59da-463a-9ddf-edd05108c19a/userFiles-5fec4b39-90e3-4402-a644-0c5314c1d0a5
[u'local-file-name.json']
{u'age': 25, u'name': u'Adam'}
...

$ cat testing2.py
import os
import json
import time
from pyspark import SparkFiles, SparkContext

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir('.'))
sc = SparkContext('local', 'App For Testing --files upload')
print(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory())
print(os.listdir(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()))
print(json.load(open(SparkFiles.get('spark-file-name.json'))))

$ spark-submit --files ../differentDirectory/local-file-name.json#spark-file-name.json testing2.py
20/08/06 17:07:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
/private/tmp/sparkSubmitTesting
['testing.py']
...
20/08/06 17:07:38 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/private/tmp/differentDirectory/local-file-name.json#spark-file-name.json does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1544)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1508)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried backslash-escaping the # (that is - `--files ../differentDirectory/local-file-name.json\#spark-file-name.json`) quote-wrapping the file path, and explicitly prepending `file://` but in all cases I get either the same error (`File <path, including fragment> does not exist`), or `Expected scheme-specific part at index 5`

MacOS, Spark v2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

A coworker pointed out that this renaming behaviour relies on YARN, which is absent when running locally - so this feature is not expected to work in my setup.